# Can InDesign combine English and Japanese text?

Tags: adobe-indesign, japanese

I need to do a project with English and Japanese text. Can InDesign use both simultaneously?

I was told no, I work in CS5. Wondering if I can avoid making a PDFs of Japanese characters and importing them into ID.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. All you need to do to use the Japanese characters is use a font that includes them. My copy of Adobe CS3 came with at least two of them, they usually are at the bottom of your font list.

It may be convenient to use the Glyphs palette (<kbd>Window > Type & Tables > Glyphs</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) to pick out what character you want.

For longer texts, I'd advise typing out the text on a Japanese keyboard and/or with software that suggests spelling based on your phonetic input. Finding characters one by one, even in the Glyphs palette is... tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely.

If you use [dynamic spelling](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/spell-checking-language-dictionaries.html) as a spellchecker, make sure you have different paragraph styles (could just use one based off your paragraph style for another language) with both English and Japanese specified as the languages, otherwise it'll be useless half the time.